# Why can we vote to close as "primarily opinion based" on meta?

Tags: discussion, closing, close-reasons, meta

Aren't almost all questions on meta primarily opinion based?

Comment: You know what you're tempting people to do, right? The basic close-vote interface is the same for all sites, metas or main. Only the custom close reasons under the "Off-topic" header are filled on a per-site basis. One of the standard close reasons is POB. (Makes much sense for main, sometimes it's even appropriate on metas.)

Comment: Well, either this question is an excellent example of a question whose answers are not based on opinion; or we should close it as a question whose answers are primarily opinion based. :-)

Comment: Some examples of questions on meta currently closed as primarily opinion-based: [Can this site be just as useful as being tutored?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/25105),
[What's the best fittest length for questions?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/12215),
[Which question on M.SE best highlights a collaborative effort?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/12415),
[Which are some of your favorite questions on this site that still have no complete answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/22128).

Comment: To a certain degree, meta is a place to discuss opinions and gauge community consensus on things.  For example, meta questions beginning with "Should" will often be inherently opinion-based.

Comment: @AsafKaragila well, that sounds like Russell's paradox, isnt it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The literal answer to the title question is in all likelihood because nobody bothered to adapt the close-dialogue for the meta site.

That said, also for a meta questions there is a scale of "opinion based"; the cut-off should certainly be very different on meta than on  main, but the notion to some degree still makes sense, which justifies what I proposed in the first sentence.

For the question in the body, literally, no, not almost all question on meta are a matter of opinion. Many a support question is fact-based. (Note: this answer is fact based :-).)

Comment: "this answer is fact based":  that's just, like, your opinion, man.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was supposed to be irony